# Why does Apache + PHP require execution permissions to write to a file?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

It has always baffled me that if a folder has read and write permissions, Apache + PHP can't write to it. You have to end giving apache execution permissions to be able to write a file in that folder. Why?

For example with chmod 664 (where the build group includes the apache user) apache won't be able to write a temporary cache file in this folder:

```
drw-rw-r--  5 jenkins build 4096 Jun 15 13:05 cache
```

while with chmod 774 apache will be able to write a new file to the folder:

```
drwxrwxr--  5 jenkins build 4096 Jun 29 11:44 cache
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need execute permission to conceptually enter a directory (cd into it, list files within, etc.).  It would have been clearer if they called this bit something else for directories.  This [article](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/aunix1/filepermissions.htm) recommends thinking of it as the "search" permission on directories.

Answer (score 2):

When these permission are set for a directory it gives ability to access metainfo and accessing to contents I think this is why you need execute.